# Possible to avoid while loop in (t)-sql when iterating over key value pair in where conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering if it is possible to avoid a for/while loop in (t)SQL in the following problem.

The are three tables:
1. CAMPAIGN: contains a campaign_id column (Camp_ID) and a date column (start_date) describing the starting date of a campaign

2. SALE: contains a customer_id column (Cust_ID), a revenue column (rev) and a date column (date) indicating the revenue by a customer on a specific date
3. SELECTION: contains the assignments of customer to marketing campaign, hence (Cust_ID) and (Camp_ID)

So what do I want to know: What revenue have customers created after the were attributed to a marketing campaign.

So mixing python and SQL

```
for (CID, SD) IN CAMPAIGN:
    SELECT Cust_ID, SUM(rev)
    FROM SALE
    JOIN SELECTION
    ON SALE.Cust_ID = SELECTION.Cust_ID
    WHERE SELECTION.Camp_Id = CID AND SALE.date > SD
```

CID and SD refer to Camp_Id and start_date of CAMPAIGN

Is it possible to replace this for loop using some elemntary sql syntax. 
I found solutions using cursors and while loops, nevertheless, there might be something more simple like some groupings and joins I don't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that condition in a `JOIN` and group by CID:

```
SELECT CAMPAIGN.CID, Cust_ID, SUM(rev)
FROM SALE
JOIN SELECTION
    ON SALE.Cust_ID = SELECTION.Cust_ID
INNER JOIN CAMPAIGN
    ON SELECTION.Camp_Id = CAMPAIGN.CID AND SALE.date > CAMPAIGN.SD
GROUP BY CAMPAIGN.CID, Cust_ID
```